# Android Gradle - add library dependency for specific configuration

Tags: android, gradle

I've an Android app in Android Studio. I'm using Gradle Version = 4.6, Android Tools Plugin Version=3.2.1. It has a app module (main) and a library module. And I hope all buildTypes depend on the same configuration.

my build.gradle(app):

```
dependencies { 
    api project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'custom')
}
```

But it is ERROR:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :lib.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code like below

```
 implementation project('path: ':lib', configuration: 'custom'')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it is not working for me